# Aggregation of a collection of object's nested array-properties

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

## Use Case

So our lead programmer loves to follow the [NIH Anti-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) and consequently I'm not allowed to use Underscore.js and can only use Vanilla JS... and we have to support IE8.

The goal is to produce an aggregation of unique values from nested collections buried within various collections of objects.

### Desired Interface

The idea is to call a function to create an aggregation function give the list of the nested properties.

#### Example

The following would flatten all `options` collection that are buried under each object within the `properties` property.

```
var allUniqueOptions = aggregateByProperty('properties', 'options');
var allUniqueDoodadsOptions = aggregateByProperty('doodad', 'properties', 'options');

allUniqueOptions(myCollection);
allUniqueDoodadsOptions(myDoodadCollection);
```

### Current Code

The code below works, but I'd like any advice on improving it for:

- performance
- readability
- any further generalization

I have a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ta3d/2/) created.

```
/* Returns the index of an object within a collection */
function arrayObjectIndexOf(arr, obj) {
    var search = JSON.stringify(obj);
    for ( var i = 0, k = arr.length; i < k; i++ ){
        if (JSON.stringify(arr[i]) == search) {
            return i;
        }
    };
    return -1;
};

/* Concatentates objects that don't exist in the source collection */
function concatIfNotExists(source, additions) {
    var result = source;
    for ( var i = 0, k = additions.length; i < k; i++ ) {
        var addition = additions[i];
        if (arrayObjectIndexOf(result, addition) === -1) {
            result.push(addition);
        }
    };
    return result;
};

/* Returns a nested collection buried within an object */
function getInnerCollection(obj, props) {
    var innerCollection = obj;

    for (var j = 0, l = props.length; j < l; j++) {
        if (innerCollection.hasOwnProperty(props[j])) {
            innerCollection = innerCollection[props[j]];
        } else {
            throw new TypeError("Property doesn't exist!");
        }
    }

    if (!innerCollection instanceof Array) {
        throw new TypeError("Inner property is not a collection!");
    }
    return innerCollection;
};

/* Returns an aggregation of objects based on collection properties */
function aggregateByProperty() {
    var props = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0);

    return function(objectCollection) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0, k = objectCollection.length; i < k; i++) {
            var innerCollection = getInnerCollection(objectCollection[i], props);
            result = concatIfNotExists(result, innerCollection);
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: Does the data always come in the format shown in the demo?

Comment: No. I'm looking for a general case since I'd like to reuse this function. However, you can always expect the parameter passed into the result function to be a collection of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a once over :

- This is a problem : `var search = JSON.stringify(obj);` because `JSON.stringify()` [does not guarantee any order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920304/7602).. To be completely correct I think you are going to need to pass the properties to `arrayObjectIndexOf` that need to get compared ( that is, if uniqueness is determined by only comparing the provided properties, otherwise you are in a world of trouble )
- `"Inner property is not a collection!"` <- Perhaps `props[l-1] + " is not an array!"`, then you will provide which property is not an array, and be clear that you are expecting an array
- `"Property doesn't exist!"` <- `"Property " + props[j] + "does not exist"` will give a better feedback as to which part is not working
- JSHint.com could only find semicolon issues, which is good

Comment: I was hoping to save an extra loop using stringify, but I can see where this path will lead to trouble... Thanks for the advice on the error handling as well! I have to be less lazy on those messages.